# Routing DSL through a switch first

Tags: networking, router

I'm thinking if the below setup is possible. My Issue is that I have FritzBox and PC in a different Room and only 1 cable through the wall from where the DSL is.
Can my Switch route the DSL connection correctly to the Router (FritzBox) and can then the Router route packages correctly to Xbox and PC?

[image: Setup]

Comment: I assume the FritzBox is the router _and_ the DSL modem? (What kind of DSL, by the way?)

Comment: I'm the FritzBox is the Router AND DSL Modem, the DSL is ADSL 2+ to be exact. It's coming through a telephone line and I'm using an adapter to use an ethernet cable.

Comment: @gempir you perfectly explained my today's question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. DSL and Ethernet connections use very different kinds of signalling – Ethernet switches won't accept a DSL link, no matter what kind of cable it runs on. (That's the reason DSL modems exist!)

So your DSL connection must go into the modem (FritzBox), and *then* it can be distributed via Ethernet. (But I don't really see an issue here: why not just swap the modem and the switch in your drawing? If FritzBox is anything like other home routers, it has a built-in 4-port switch anyway, so you can connect the Xbox *and* the Room 2 cable.)

If the issue is poor Wi-Fi signal, buy a second access point (aka "wireless extender" – or convert a wireless router into one).

Comment: Alright thanks. Was hoping somehow my switch could route it anyway, but I guess I'll need another cable.

Comment: Why do you need another cable? From your diagram, I don't see any specific reason. You said the cable between rooms is suitable for Ethernet, anyway.

Comment: Xbox, DSL are in 1 Room and FritzBox, PC are in the other Room. I need to first route 1 cable from DSL to FritzBox then 1 BACK to the Xbox.

Comment: I'd move the FritzBox to room 1 (where DSL is)...

Comment: Yeah I prefer it this way, because Room 2 is the Office and it's the best position in terms of Wifi. Also I don't like to clutter Room 1 with too much Networking stuff.